# Why not enable sqlite3 callback tracebacks

Tags: python, sqlite

In the python sqlite3 library there is a function you can call to enable tracebacks in user-defined sqlite callback functions:
[sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(flag)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks)

This is disabled by default.
Are there any downsides to enabling it?